# Parameter $this->data by default when loading a view

Tags: php, codeigniter

When using CodeIgniter views, I put information to be parsed in under a model $this->data (title/description, dynamically changed menu, view-only user info and so forth) and loads the views invariably with that second parameter.

I would like to know if it is possible to pass $this->data by default when loading a view, so that `$this->load->view('header')` means the same as `$this->load->view('header',$this->data)` without having to change the core. Hooks maybe?

It is simply a manner of efficiency in coding rather than a necessity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a simple helper function for this which I autoload in config/autoload.php

helpers/template_helper.php

```
//loads the view file
function ldview($view_name) {
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->view($view_name,$CI->data);
}

// returns the string view
function strview($view_name) {
    $CI =& get_instance();
    return $CI->load->view($view_name,$CI->data, TRUE);
}
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! I like when solutions use existing structure in the most simple and effective way :)